# Validate windows user against LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, single-sign-on

I have the following problem:

I have a rich client (Java) running on my desktop computer, which communicates with a server. When you start the rich client, it prompts for your user name and password. The rich client will send it to the server which will say "yes, access allowed" or "no access".

Now we want to provide a little bit more user experience: When a user is logged-in to Windows and starts the rich client, the rich client should automatically check the current user and ask an LDAP (Active Directory) whether this user is allowed or not.

I'm completely new to LDAP, but I figured out the following so far:

I can get the current user by:

```
userName = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName();
```

I can get it's domain using Waffle like this:

```
WindowsAuthProviderImpl auth = new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();

for(IWindowsDomain domain : auth.getDomains())
    userDomain = domain.getFqn();
```

Now I can take some known LDAP account to look-up this particular user:

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "123");

DirContext context = LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance("ldap://host:12345/", props);
String filter = "(& (userPrincipalName=" + userName + "@" + userDomain + ")(objectClass=user))";

SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

context.search(dc, filter, controls);
```

At the end, I got the information about the user I wanted. But:

1. Is it save? Or can someone easily fake it's user-name and domain?
2. I want to get rid of the "admin" user to connect to the LDAP server. I want to take the current user and try to connect with it. But how? To connect to the LDAP server I need a password and Windows will - of course - not give it to me.

**So, how can I validate/check the current logged-in user in Windows against LDAP?**

What I did so far seems complicated and feels wrong. I think I didn't get the point...

**EDIT:**

I know that I can also get the groups of the current user from Waffle like this:

```
WindowsAuthProviderImpl auth = new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
IWindowsIdentity identity = auth.logonUser(user, pwd);
for(IWindowsAccount group : identity.getGroups())
    group.getFqn();
```

However, I need a password again although I'm already logged in on Windows...

Comment: Hi. I know this is old, but I ran over your post while trying to implement a SSO for windows. I had a similar problem and I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288761/single-sign-on-with-java-client/50487105#50487105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK, there is no method to obtain the password from Microsoft Active Directory.

You do not say why you need the user's password, but you might be able to use the Kerberos Ticket.

-jim